Quiero agregar una condicion para que cambie de color un input segun la condicion especificada


<script type="module">
        import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signOut } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-auth.js";
        import { auth, db } from './firebase-config.js';
        import { collection, addDoc } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-firestore.js";

        let currentUser;

        // Verificar el estado de autenticación
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if (!user) {
                window.location.href = 'index.html';
            } else {
                currentUser = user;
                document.getElementById('userEmail').textContent = user.displayName || user.email;
            }
        });

        // Cerrar sesión
        document.getElementById('logout').addEventListener('click', () => {
            signOut(auth).then(() => {
                window.location.href = 'index.html';
            });
        });

        const productsBody = document.getElementById('productsBody');
        const addProductBtn = document.getElementById('addProduct');
        const salesForm = document.getElementById('salesForm');
        const totalUnitCostInput = document.getElementById('totalUnitCost');
        const totalFinalPriceInput = document.getElementById('totalFinalPrice');
        const totalUnitProfitInput = document.getElementById('totalUnitProfit');
        const titheInput = document.getElementById('tithe');
        const totalBudgetInput = document.getElementById('totalBudget');

        addProductBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const newRow = document.createElement('tr');
            newRow.innerHTML = `
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="product" required></td>
                <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" required></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control unit-cost" name="unitCost" required></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control final-price" name="finalPrice" required></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control unit-profit" name="unitProfit" readonly></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-product">Eliminar</button></td>
            `;
            productsBody.appendChild(newRow);

            newRow.querySelector('.remove-product').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                event.target.closest('tr').remove();
                updateTotals();
            });

            newRow.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
                input.addEventListener('input', updateTotals);
            });
        });

        productsBody.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
            input.addEventListener('input', updateTotals);
        });

        totalBudgetInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
            formatTotalBudget();
            updateTotals();
        });

        function formatTotalBudget() {
            const value = parseFloat(totalBudgetInput.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) || 0;
            totalBudgetInput.value = value.toLocaleString('es-ES');
        }

        function updateTotals() {
            let totalUnitCost = 0;
            let totalFinalPrice = 0;
            let totalUnitProfit = 0;

            productsBody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(row => {
                const quantity = parseFloat(row.querySelector('input[name="quantity"]').value) || 0;
                const unitCostInput = row.querySelector('input[name="unitCost"]');
                const finalPriceInput = row.querySelector('input[name="finalPrice"]');
                const unitProfitInput = row.querySelector('input[name="unitProfit"]');

                const unitCost = parseFloat(unitCostInput.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) || 0;
                const finalPrice = parseFloat(finalPriceInput.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) || 0;
                const unitProfit = finalPrice - unitCost;

                totalUnitCost += quantity * unitCost;
                totalFinalPrice += quantity * finalPrice;
                totalUnitProfit += quantity * unitProfit;

                unitCostInput.value = unitCost.toLocaleString('es-ES');
                finalPriceInput.value = finalPrice.toLocaleString('es-ES');
                unitProfitInput.value = unitProfit.toLocaleString('es-ES');
            });

            totalUnitCostInput.value = totalUnitCost.toLocaleString('es-ES');
            totalFinalPriceInput.value = totalFinalPrice.toLocaleString('es-ES');
            totalUnitProfitInput.value = totalUnitProfit.toLocaleString('es-ES');
            titheInput.value = (totalUnitProfit * 0.10).toLocaleString('es-ES');

            const totalBudget = parseFloat(totalBudgetInput.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) || 0;
            if (totalFinalPrice !== totalBudget) {
                totalFinalPriceInput.classList.add('error-background');
            } else {
                totalFinalPriceInput.classList.remove('error-background');
            }
        }

        salesForm.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const saleDate = document.getElementById('saleDate').value;
            const client = document.getElementById('client').value;
            const totalBudget = parseFloat(totalBudgetInput.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
            const totalUnitCost = parseFloat(totalUnitCostInput.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
            const totalFinalPrice = parseFloat(totalFinalPriceInput.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
            const totalUnitProfit = parseFloat(totalUnitProfitInput.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
            const tithe = parseFloat(titheInput.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));

            const products = [];
            productsBody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(row => {
                const product = row.querySelector('input[name="product"]').value;
                const quantity = parseFloat(row.querySelector('input[name="quantity"]').value);
                const unitCost = parseFloat(row.querySelector('input[name="unitCost"]').value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
                const finalPrice = parseFloat(row.querySelector('input[name="finalPrice"]').value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));

                products.push({ product, quantity, unitCost, finalPrice });
            });

            try {
                await addDoc(collection(db, 'ventas'), {
                    uid: currentUser.uid,
                    saleDate,
                    client,
                    totalBudget,
                    totalUnitCost,
                    totalFinalPrice,
                    totalUnitProfit,
                    tithe,
                    products,
                    createdAt: new Date()
                });

                alert('Venta registrada con éxito');
                salesForm.reset();
                productsBody.innerHTML = `
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="product" required></td>
                        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" required></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control unit-cost" name="unitCost" required></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control final-price" name="finalPrice" required></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control unit-profit" name="unitProfit" readonly></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-product">Eliminar</button></td>
                    </tr>
                `;
                updateTotals();
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error registrando la venta: ', error);
                alert('Hubo un problema al registrar la venta. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo.');
            }
        });
    </script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registrar Venta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .container {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .table td, .table th {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .table tfoot td {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .total-label {
            background-color: #f8f9fa;
        }
        .total-value {
            background-color: #e9ecef;
        }
        .highlight {
            background-color: #d1ecf1;
            color: #0c5460;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .spacer {
            height: 10px;
        }
        .error-background {
            background-color: #f8d7da;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Finanzas</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="registrar_ingreso.html">Registrar Ingreso</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="registrar_gasto.html">Registrar Gasto</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="ingresos.html">Mis Ingresos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="gastos.html">Mis Gastos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="resumen.html">Resumen</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <span class="navbar-text" id="userEmail"></span>
            <button id="logout" class="btn btn-danger ml-2">Logout</button>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Registrar Venta</h1>
        <form id="salesForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="saleDate">Fecha:</label>
                <input type="date" id="saleDate" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="client">Cliente:</label>
                <input type="text" id="client" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="totalBudget">Monto Total del Presupuesto:</label>
                <input type="text" id="totalBudget" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive mt-4">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="productsTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Producto</th>
                            <th>Cantidad</th>
                            <th>Costo Unitario</th>
                            <th>Precio Final</th>
                            <th>Ganancia Unitaria</th>
                            <th>Acciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="productsBody">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="product" required></td>
                            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" required></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control unit-cost" name="unitCost" required></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control final-price" name="finalPrice" required></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control unit-profit" name="unitProfit" readonly></td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-product">Eliminar</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6" class="spacer"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"></td>
                            <td class="total-label">Costo Total:</td>
                            <td class="total-label">Precio Final Total:</td>
                            <td class="total-label">Ganancia Total Final:</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="totalUnitCost" class="form-control total-value" readonly></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="totalFinalPrice" class="form-control total-value" readonly></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="totalUnitProfit" class="form-control total-value highlight" readonly></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addProduct">Agregar Producto</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
                <label for="tithe">Diezmo:</label>
                <input type="text" id="tithe" class="form-control highlight" readonly>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registrar Venta</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



Estoy queriendo agregar una condicion que el input  Precio Final Total: cambie a rojo o se torne rojo mientras no coincida con el input Monto Total del Presupuesto: cuando coincida debe estar en color verde y asi dinamicamente eso no lo estoy pudiendo lograr
Estoy queriendo agregar una condicion que el input  Precio Final Total: cambie a rojo o se torne rojo mientras no coincida con el input Monto Total del Presupuesto: cuando coincida debe estar en color verde y asi dinamicamente eso no lo estoy pudiendo lograr

Hay demasiado código en tu pregunta, lo que dificulta muchísimo la revisión del problema.
Trata de dejar solo el código necesario para que podamos revisar de forma más efectiva el inconveniente.
Mientras, te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacer que cambien los colores del input en función de la comparación de los valores de los dos input que mencionas. La idea es crear dos clases en el código CSS y agregarlas o quitarlas al comparar los valores.
Adapta este código a tu proyecto y cuéntanos que tal te va.
Si te quedan dudas al respecto, deja un comentario.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //Obtener los valores de los input
  const montoPresupuesto = document.getElementById('monto-presupuesto');
  const precioFinal = document.getElementById('precio-final');

  function compararValores() {
    //Agregar o remover las clases dinámicamente en función de la coincidencia de los valores
    if (montoPresupuesto.value === precioFinal.value) {
      precioFinal.classList.remove('diferente');
      precioFinal.classList.add('coincide');
    } else {
      precioFinal.classList.remove('coincide');
      precioFinal.classList.add('diferente');
    }
  }
  //Ejecutar el listener cada vez que los valores cambien
  montoPresupuesto.addEventListener('input', compararValores);
  precioFinal.addEventListener('input', compararValores);
});
.coincide {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.diferente {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Comparar Montos</title>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="monto-presupuesto">Monto Total del Presupuesto:</label>
  <input type="number" id="monto-presupuesto" name="monto-presupuesto">
  <br>
  <label for="precio-final">Precio Final Total:</label>
  <input type="number" id="precio-final" name="precio-final">

</body>

</html>



